# Why does flush() effect println() on PrintWriter

Tags: java, stream

I have the basic code for a server:

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(14000);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        String incoming;
        while((incoming = in.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("Client Says: " + incoming);
            out.println("Client Says: " + incoming);
            out.flush();
            //if(incoming.equals("HELLO")) break;
        }
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
```

I'm trying to further understand streams as they're giving me some serious headaches. From what I've read, println methods automatically flush for you, however this line is not delivered to the client unless the flush method is called afterwards? I'm just looking for a nice solid explanation of this?

Comment: Alas, as usual you spend a few hours researching something and as soon as you post the question you realise the answer. PrintWriter requires auto flush to be set to true.

Comment: You may want to write an answer to your own question and self-accept it.

Comment: it is good for network app to *not* auto flush.

Comment: Why is it a good idea not to auto flush?

Comment: flush is expensive. you don't want accidental flush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable automatic flushing of the PrintWriter, the second argument of its constructor must be set to true.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before, just:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

That will make the difference. If you do not autoflush you can get some errors or receive data as null, it happened to me some time ago. Best regards.